# I can't understand the meaning of this paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context, as

> she wants to manipulate you into committing as she knows that you as a man want to have sex, and therefore will force you to commit to a relationship before giving you all the fun.

two consecutive "as"s makes me confusing!!

she wants to manipulate me into committing WHAT??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sometimes As is used as "Since"**

**As** and **since** are used when the reason is already well known and is therefore usually less important. The ***as or since*** clause is usually (Not always) placed at the beginning of the sentence:

> As the performance had already started, we went up to the balcony and occupied some empty seats there.
>
> Since John had already eaten, I made do with a sandwich.

That's why you're confused. In the text **As** is used as **since**. The second **As** doesn't have anything to do with the first. They're not using it for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "committing" is given later in the sentence, when is elaborated. "Committing to..."